# Firebase auth.SignOut() on Unity project

Tags: c#, authentication, firebase, unity-game-engine, backend

I've been having this problem for some time. Every time I let the user log out and try to let it connect again, the application freezes and crash. Any idea what could be happening?

Ps .: At first I thought the reason was to have more than one script dealing with firebase behaviors (I restart the SplashScreen scene where a gameobject was instantiated with the "DontDestroyOnLoad ()" method of unity). So I ended up in some duplicate scripts and I figured it was this could be causing the crash, but I've already fixed that and the crash continues.

Edit: Here is the code I use to signin the user

```
public void SignInWithCredentials(string email, string password) {
    if (auth.CurrentUser == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) {
        Credential credential = EmailAuthProvider.GetCredential(email, password);
        auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsCanceled) {
                Debug.Log("------------------------- User sign in canceled.");
            } else if (task.IsFaulted) {
                Debug.Log("------------------------- User sign in encountered an error.");

                ButtonManager.Instance.panelLoginInfo.GetComponent<UIControllerExample>().Play();

                foreach (var e in task.Exception.InnerExceptions) {
                    FirebaseException firebaseException = (FirebaseException)e;
                    Debug.Log("------------------------- " + firebaseException.Message);
                }
            } else if (task.IsCompleted) {
                Debug.Log("------------------------- User sign in completed.");
                if (auth.CurrentUser != null) {
                    Debug.Log("------------------------- User info: " + auth.CurrentUser.Email + "    " + auth.CurrentUser.ProviderId);
                }

                if (!auth.CurrentUser.IsEmailVerified) {
                    Debug.Log("------------------------- User not comfirmed your email. Send new verification.");
                    auth.CurrentUser.SendEmailVerificationAsync().ContinueWith(taskVerification => {
                        if (taskVerification.IsCanceled) {
                            Debug.Log("------------------------- User verification email canceled send.");
                        } else if (taskVerification.IsFaulted) {
                            Debug.Log("------------------------- User verification email encountered an error.");
                            foreach (var e in task.Exception.InnerExceptions) {
                                FirebaseException firebaseException = (FirebaseException)e;
                                Debug.Log("------------------------- " + firebaseException.Message);
                            }
                        } else if (taskVerification.IsCompleted) {
                            Debug.Log("------------------------- User verification email send.");

                            SaveSession.Instance.SaveUserCredentials();
                            StartCoroutine(WaitToLoadScene("EmailCheck"));
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Debug.Log("------------------------- User confirmed your email.");

                    SaveSession.Instance.SaveUserCredentials();
                    StartCoroutine(WaitToLoadScene("City"));
                }

            } else {
                Debug.Log("------------------------- Something really really wrong happen.");
            }
        });
    } else if (auth.CurrentUser != null) {
        Debug.Log("------------------------- You have user logged in: " + auth.CurrentUser.Email);
    } else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) {
        Debug.Log("------------------------- Complete all blanck spaces.");
    }
}
```

And this the code I use to logout user:

```
public void LogOut () {
    auth.SignOut();
    user.DeleteAsync();

    if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
        FacebookManager.Instance.isLogIn = "false";
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("Login", FacebookManager.Instance.isLogIn);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        FB.LogOut();
    }

    if (File.Exists(credentialsPath)) {
        File.Delete(credentialsPath);
    }

    StartCoroutine(WaitToLoadScene("SplashScreen"));
}
```

Comment: Probably adding your log in and log out script might help. And are you using the email and password authentication or Google or Facebook...

Comment: Alright I edit the post with the code I'm using. Apparently this error only occurs by email authentication, because I not see this error when I do this with FB auth token. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You're not getting any error when it crashes or it's like unity freezes?

Comment: No, the profiler on Unity just stuck and the logcat show nothing about that

Comment: Try to debug your code step by step so you can find the line that causes the problem.

Comment: Okay, I did a test with a new scene where I just let the user log in with email and password and then disconnected it by calling a function from the firebase itself "Firebase.Authentication.SignOut ()", without any other add-on and even then The application (in android) freezes and crash. Could this be a bug in the SDK? I tried to talk to Firebase by email, but the answers did not help me much.